# DateTimeFormatter in Android not parsing a Timestamp properly

Tags: java, kotlin, datetimeformatter

I am trying to parse a timestamp that looks like this according to the error I was given. Attached below is my code for parsing, I followed the documentation regarding the symbols like u,y,M,h,H in DateTimeFormatter so I am quite confused why it is not working? Thank you.

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-12-26T14:52:02+08:00' could not be parsed at index 19

```
@Composable
fun ExpandedBusStop(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    currentBusStopService: SingaporeBusServices,

) {
    // Determine the Current Timestamp as LocalDateTime
    var currentTimestamp = LocalDateTime.now() //.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
    val datetimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
//    datetimeFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+14"))
    var nextBusEtaArray = Array<String>(3) { "" }
    var nextBusOccupancyArray = Array<String>(3) { "" }

    val currentBusService = currentBusStopService.busServiceNumber


    for (i: Int in 0..2) {
        // Determining the ETA of the Next 3 Buses in Minutes
        val nextBus = currentBusStopService.nextBus1
        val nextBusTimestampString = nextBus.estimatedArrival  // In the Event there are no longer any buses
        val nextBusTimestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(nextBusTimestampString, datetimeFormatter)
        val nextBusETA = Duration.between(currentTimestamp, nextBusTimestamp)
        // Round down to Nearest Minute and Convert into a String
        nextBusEtaArray[i] = nextBusETA.toString().toInt().toString()

        // Determining the Occupancy Rates of the Next 3 Buses
        val nextBusOccupancy = nextBus.busOccupancyLevels
        nextBusOccupancyArray[i] = nextBusOccupancy
    }


    Divider(thickness = 2.dp)
    Row {
        // Bus Service Number
        Text(
            text = currentBusService,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
            modifier = modifier.weight(2f)
        )

        Spacer(modifier = modifier.weight(1f))

        // Waiting Time + Occupancy Rate for each Incoming Bus
        Column() {
            Text(
                text = nextBusEtaArray[0],
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )

            // TODO Replace with Infographic
            Text(
                text = nextBusOccupancyArray[0],
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )

        }

        Column() {
            Text(
                text = nextBusEtaArray[1],
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )

            // TODO Replace with Infographic
            Text(
                text = nextBusOccupancyArray[0],
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )
        }

        Column() {
            Text(
                text = nextBusEtaArray[2],
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )

            // TODO Replace with Infographic
            Text(
                text = nextBusOccupancyArray[0],
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )
        }
    }
    Divider(thickness = 2.dp)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter`

`java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. your date-time string, `2022-12-26T14:52:02+08:00`).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "2022-12-26T14:52:02+08:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-12-26T14:52:02+08:00
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: I see, but isn't a DateTimeFormatter used to convert the string "2022-12-26T14:52:02+08:00" into another data type like Temporal in Android? Thank you

Comment: It all depends on your use case. Temporal is a top-level interface in `java.time API and `OffsetDateTime` is one of the implementing classes. You can learn more about it from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html). Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I see, I think I understand!! I'll spend some more time with the documentations. Thank you :>

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) docs:

> Offset Z: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern
> letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute,
> without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the
> offset is zero. Four letters outputs the full form of localized
> offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the
> corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero. **Five
> letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero,
> with colon.** It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero. Six or more
> letters throws IllegalArgumentException.

Hence the correct pattern you should use is this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ
```

The snippet below works correctly and prints out "{OffsetSeconds=28800, InstantSeconds=1672037522},ISO resolved to 2022-12-26T14:52:02":

```
fun main() {
  val datetimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ")
  println(datetimeFormatter.parse("2022-12-26T14:52:02+08:00"))
}
```